# HTML Links are lost during print to pdf in Chrome/Firefox when any children of anchor tag has position:absolute

Tags: html, pdf, chromium

Hyperlink is lost during print to PDF conversion in Chrome and Firefox.

I tried using Chromium headless browser to create PDF from HTML as well and same behaviour is observed.

Steps to reproduce the issue:

(1) Create a HTML file with  tag
(2) Create any tag

or  or  tag which has "position:absolute" in the style.
(3) Print the HTML file to PDF

**Sample HTML Snippet:**

```
<html>
<body>
    <a href="https://www.google.com">
        <p style="position: absolute;"> Hello </p>
    </a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

`a` tag is an inline element, which means it takes space as the content size. But in the example, the content is absolutely positioned, which leads the **width** and **height** of the `a` tag as 0.

So, you should make the **a** tag as **block** or **inline block** element and give width and height.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <a
      href="https://www.google.com"
      style="position: relative; display: block; width: 100px; height: 100px;"
    >
      <p style="position: absolute">Hello</p>
    </a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you confirm if the hyperlink works in the PDF that you saved using "Save as PDF"? I just tried and it doesn't work.

Comment: @AravinthChellathurai updated the answer, hope this does work for you!

Answer (score 0):

If you try having the anchor element inside the block-level paragraph it may work better for you:

```
<html>
<body>
<p style="position: absolute;">
    <a href="https://www.google.com">
         Hello
    </a>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But, I have a use case to have "position: absolute;" inside the anchor tag.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the link disruptive embedded `<p>` and `</p>` it will work perfectly as a designed hyperlink.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]